# Subscriber providing condition for another subscriber to subscribe a topic

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to generate a node which subscribes 2 topics and uses one topic as a condition to subscribe another topic:

```
class odom2obj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._pose_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/chatter', Pose, self._check_obj)

    def _check_obj(self):
        if self._pose_sub.num_object > 0:
            # subscribe another topic # 
            # self._odom_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/chatter2', Pose, self._callback) #

    def _callback(self):

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('hsr_odom2obj') 
    odom2obj()
    rospy.spin()
```

I was initially thinking of setting 2nd subscriber into 1st subscriber's callback function. However, I now wonder whether this is an efficient approach when the callback function of the 1st subscriber is called often. I appreciate if someone can tell any better way.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389391/subscriber-providing-condition-for-another-subscriber-to-subscribe-a-topic/) by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2021-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to use data from rostopics which get generated by built-in ros driver. So, what I did was declaring another node which subscribes both topics using message filter and decides to process the data based on the condition.

---

Originally posted by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) with karma: 38 on 2021-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0